# Schedule Eclipse to run JUnit4 tests overnight

Tags: eclipse, junit, ibm-midrange

How would one schedule JUnit to run all tests at a specified time?  Currently wondering about setting up a cron job or a timer. The ideal solution would wake up and run all tests in a project, similar to what you get when you right-click > Run As > JUnit Test.

Current landscape:

- We are using junit4 to test remote procedure calls.
- Stored procedure calls execute through JDBC against DB2 on iSeries.
- Program source code is RPG lives/is managed on an iSeries.
- Test code is java in Eclipse.  JUnit4 is installed and working.
- The tests are working when run from eclipse.

I'm intrigued by continuous integration tools--we use Jenkins to manage some source code and testing--but I think having our source on the i blows that up.  So, I'd like to run all tests overnight against the prior day's code changes.

I'm not against setting up Ant or whatever, but I'm not really interested in creating an maintaining a test suite. Each night, run the tests that exist over the programs that exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to first use maven - i.e mavenise your project to remove the dependency on Eclipse. Then tests can be easily compiled and run from command line. Ant could also be used to do this but Maven is a much cleaner solution. 
To run them regularly every night, I would definitely suggest a continuous integration tool like Jenkins both for it's ease of configurability and  it's reporting mechanism - it generates great easily accessible test reports.
What is the problem you face in setting up Jenkins on iSeries?

Comment: If I understand continuous integration, it's running tests as programs are promoted. There is no programatic cross-reference between the program source and test source, and no way to say "if program xyz is being promoted, testXyx should run.  Sounds like I might need another look at Jenkins.

Comment: Using maven, it is easy to build components where each component contains code and test. Then maven can be used to build necessary components which includes compile and test of that component. Even if you do not use Maven,  you can configure Jenkins any way you want - i.e you could have a Pre-build step that compiles code using ANT and then a Build-Step that uses ant/junit to run your tests. You can configure a Jenkins job anyway you want to build code  in a defined sequence using a build tool like ant or maven.